# Quickest way to replace associative array keys with numerical keys

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

I have an array:

```
array('something' => 'like this', 'something' => 'like this', 'something' => 'like this');
```

I would like to replace it (quickly as possible, using a simple inline function) to be like this:

```
array(0 => 'like this', 1 => 'like this', 2 => 'like this');
```

Possible using any built-in php-array functions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

check out [**array_values**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$new_array=array_values($array);
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
             'something'=>'something',
             'something'=>'something'
             );

$new_arr = array();
$new_arr = array_values(arr);

    print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything to the original array, thats for sure

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = array(
    'something'=>'something',
    'something'=>'something'
);

sort($arr);

print_r($arr);
```